# Second order quantifier out of scope of first order quantifier in prefix

Tags: logic, quantifiers

In turning first/second order formula into Prenex form, it seems that second order quantifiers may fall under the scope of first order quantifiers or vice-versa in the prefix. The matrix is quantifier free.

My question is under what conditions we are allowed to bring second order quantifiers out of the scope of first order quantifiers within the prefix?

The section 3.3 in 
https://www.logic.at/lvas/185301/Leivant_higher-order-logic.pdf

mentions that transformation, but it is not very clear explanation.

Comment: According to your reference, you are not allowed to just bring them out when the quantifiers alternate. When you switch them you *also* have to replace every entry of the quantified function symbol in the matrix by a new function symbol. This new symbol has the variables quantified by the first order quantifier(s) you switched the function quantifier with as additional arguments. For example, ∃x∀f ∃y P(x,f(y))=∀g∃x∃y P(x,g(x,y)).

Comment: "This new symbol has the variables quantified by the first order quantifier(s) you switched the function quantifier with as additional arguments." What do you mean by this. I have problem understanding the construction of g(x,y), if you can explain that.

Comment: There is no construction. Just add an extra variable quantified by the switched quantifier to whatever f had and call the new function g. The idea is that when ∃x went first the choice of f depended on x implicitly, so when we put g first we have to make the dependence explicit.

Comment: So the dependence on x is to be made explicit only when we have dual quantifiers. For same quantifiers swap, we have no issue why? Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Yes, the dependence is only introduces by alternation. We can state that various things exist, or that something holds for everything, in any order. It is the same already with the first order quantifiers, identical ones can be permuted as one wishes.